# Android save details screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am working on a small project that requires a details screen where the user inputs his details and they are permanently stored. The user must have the option to change the details as well if he needs to do so. I looked into the saved preferences library however it does not seem to offer such functionality.

To give a visual idea of what is required, something like this screen should be fine:

http://www.google.com.mt/imgres?start=97&num=10&hl=en&tbo=d&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbnid=aQSZz782gIfOeM:&imgrefurl=http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2011/10/iphone-web-application-development-with.html&docid=YpPF3-T8zLGOAM&imgurl=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-YRISJXXajD0/Tq2KTpcqWiI/AAAAAAAAFiE/-aJen8IuVRM/s1600/7.png&w=365&h=712&ei=rbX6ULTDCOfV4gTroIDoCg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=834&vpy=218&dur=2075&hovh=314&hovw=161&tx=80&ty=216&sig=108811856681773622351&page=4&tbnh=155&tbnw=79&ndsp=35&ved=1t:429,r:4,s:100,i:16

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SharedPreferences` would be perfect for this kind of small amount of data which you want to store persistently.

```
// 'this' is simply your Application Context, so you can access this nearly anywhere
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To obtain from the preferences:

```
// You can equally use KEY_LAST_NAME to get the last name, etc. They are just key/value pairs
// Note that the 2nd arg is simply the default value if there is no key/value mapping
String firstName = prefs.getString(KEY_FIRST_NAME_CONSTANT, "");
```

Or to save:

```
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
// firstName being the text they entered in the EditText
editor.putString(KEY_FIRST_NAME_CONSTANT, firstName);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could easily use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store user's details. Everytime the Preference screen is opened the stored data can then be extracted from the Shared Preferences and presented to the user for edit. ONce the edit is done the new data can be updated back in the the Shared Preferences.

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) thread to see how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve such functionality using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) Class in android.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle object){
             super.onCreate(object);
             // Initialize UI and link xml data to java view objects
              ......
              SharedPreferences myPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
              nameView.setText(myPref.getString("USER_NAME", null));
              passView.setText(myPref.getString("PASSWORD", null));

      }
public void onStop(){
             super.onStop();
             if (isFinishing()) {

             getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
             .putString("USER_NAME", nameView.getText().toString())
             .putString("PASSWORD",  passView.getText().toString())
             .commit()

             }
 }
```